# trying to pass the string value to print

Tags: bash, scripting

Through bash shell script, i am trying to read a file name.

```
    for File in `ls -1 ${OFSR_IN}/FACT_PEOPLE_*.txt`
     do
      File_name=`basename ${File}`
      EXT_YEARMTH=`basename ${File} .txt | cut -c13-`

      echo ${EXT_YEARMTH}
      echo  ${File_name}

      #OfsrHRSPeople05Loa
      echo "\$InputFile_People=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\'${File_name}'" >>  ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm
      echo "\$\$HR_YEARMONTH=${EXT_YEARMTH}" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm
    done


I am trying to print the value of File_name in output file config.prm







    echo "\$InputFile_People=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\${File_name}" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/config.prm
echo "\$\$HR_YEARMONTH=${EXT_YEARMTH}" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm
```

I am not able to print correct file name such as filename_201401.txt

i am getting out put as

```
 $InputFile_People=$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\'FACT_PEOPLE_201306.txt'
$$HR_YEARMONTH=201401
```

I am expecting my output as without quotes in file name

```
    $InputFile_People=$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\FACT_PEOPLE_201306.txt
$$HR_YEARMONTH=201401
```

Comment: Don't parse the output from `ls`. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Please little bit more information.

Comment: What about your script isn't working exactly?

Comment: i am getting the out as below:$InputFile_People=$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in${File_name_in}

Comment: expecting as $InputFile_People=$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\filename_201401.txt

Comment: You are escaping the `$` used for the `${File_name}` part of your argument to echo. You are telling the shell not to substitute the variable value in its place. Drop the erroneous `\\` there.

Comment: The below path: $PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\ this is windows folder path. for further program i am asking to read the file. hence i can not drop \then file name

Comment: in the same i am able to pass the number value, but not the string value

Comment: If you need literal slashes in the output then you need to escape them in double quotes (or use single quotes). So `"\\${File_name}"` or `'\'"${File_name}"` or something like that.

Comment: when i use \'${File_name}' then i am getting folder path $PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\'filename_2014.txt. i does not want in quotes

Comment: I never said use `\'${File_name}`. Look again.

Comment: i have not done as per yours. it is my try. But with the double quotes, i am not able to run. It failed to read.

Comment: Does `echo "\$InputFile_People=\\\$PMRootDir\\rlhrs\\data\\in\\${File_name}"` do what you want? I'm assuming `$InputFile` and `$PMRootDir` want to be literals in the output.

Comment: $PMRootDir - substitued as e:\file\ (like folder path from another shell). $Inputfile is coming from the above as filename_201401.txt

Comment: So `$InputFile` and `$PMRootDir` are also variables in your script? Because neither of them are in your snippet. Then try `echo "\\${InputFile}_People=\\$PMRootDir\\rlhrs\\data\\in\\${File_name}".

Comment: I am sorry i am not able to get the correct result.

Comment: Hi Reisner, is there any other solution?

Comment: Update your post to include your current attempted echo line, a sample input file name, **exactly** what you get as output from echo, and **exactly** what output you want for that sample file.

Comment: I am reading more than one file in windows folder. But through bash scripting i am reading the files in for loop. When i read first file (filename_201401.txt). then i have to create file so that informatica mapping process the file name. then it again comeback for next file until end of all files processed. echo "\$InputFile_People=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\Fact_People_" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm

Comment: Do what I asked please. Update **your original post** with the information I asked for. All of it.

Comment: not able to accommodate the code the space available

Comment: export FIRSTSTEP=1
export LASTSTEP=1

export OFSR_FU=RLHRS
. ${OFSR_ROOT}/common/bin/LoadVariables.bash
. ${OFSR_ROOT}/common/bin/CommonFunctions.bash
. ${OFSR_CFG}/LoadHRSvariables.bash

partition=${PART_YEARMTH} 
#IN_FILE=FACT_PEOPLE_*

SESSION_PM=s_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa

Comment: STEP1()
{

for File in `ls ${OFSR_IN}/FACT_PEOPLE_*.txt`
do
 File_name=`basename ${File}`
 #File_name_in=`basename ${File} .txt | cut -c1-`
 EXT_YEARMTH=`basename ${File} .txt | cut -c13-`
 
 echo ${EXT_YEARMTH}
 echo ${File_name}
 #echo ${File_name_in}

Comment: #OfsrHRSPeople05Loa
  echo ";\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\config\pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm" > ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm
  echo "\$PMSessionLogFile=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\trace\s_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.log" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm
  echo "\$InputFile_People=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\Fact_People" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm
  echo "\$\$HR_YEARMONTH=${EXT_YEARMTH}" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm
done

Comment: **Update the original post**. Stop using comments.

Comment: sorry i understood wrongly. But main content is same

Comment: You had to break the code up in weird ways, formatting is awful, please just update the post with the data in a sanely viewable fashion.

Comment: @user1468031 Please know that people wants to give you the real answer in one go, not just an answer in which you'd keep asking again again for other failures you didn't expect that is why it's important that you give everything you want to do. Give complete example. There's something wrong with what you're dong: 1) You're writing multiple lines of `$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\something.txt` and not just one. Is that intended. Wouldn't `$InputFile_People` be reassigned repeatedly in that config file?

Comment: Second, how about if your config file already exists. Wouldn't `>>` add more data to it? How about the old data that were already there? Wouldn't it cause redundancy? You may actually be deleting the file at the beginning of the code but *we don't want to guess* and update our answers that's why you have to give everything. Modify your post (not make comments) and place 3 sections: 1) Your -complete- code. 2) Example input when necessary. 3) Your wanted output. The *final* one that you wanted. Format it properly so people can understand and help you easy. Again, we don't want to **guess**.

Comment: For your question on creating file for n number of files, we are overwriting the same, then run informatica mapping for processing the file with certain information from file name

Comment: my output should like this: $InputFile_People=$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\filename_201401.txt

Comment: What is your output file intended to be read or used by? If you needed correct shell quoting, for instance, `printf %q` would be appropriate.

Comment: i updated my question with current code, output i am getting now, expected output

Comment: Change       `echo "\$InputFile_People=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\'${File_name}'" >>  ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm` to       `echo "\$InputFile_People=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\\${File_name}" >> "${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm"`

Comment: Yes your change is working great. thanks so much

Comment: i need one more help. Now i am able to extract yearmonth like 201401. i want to put 2014/01. how do i this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. Use "ls -1" instead of just ls in your for loop.
2. escape the backslash in echo statement

   ***echo "${InputFile_People}=${PMRootDir}\rlhrs\data\in\${File_name}" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/config.prm***

Also please share some sample output you are expecting out of echo statement. it helps in understanding the problem better.

Comment: Please share how do i do the echo with backslash: my current statment is echo ${File_name}

Comment: @user1468031 echo "\${FILENAME}" can you share a sample output you want?

Comment: i updated my question again with my code, output i am getting, expected output now

Comment: ...this would be more correctly written as: `for File in "${OFSR_IN}/FACT_PEOPLE_"*.txt`.

Comment: if i do this, my other variable ie yearmonth is also not working. Now i added that code as well now. and also handling multiple files in this loop with different file name and year month.

Comment: i need one more help. Now i am able to extract yearmonth like 201401. i want to put 2014/01. how do i this?

Comment: You can use sed command to include "/" in the output.. for e.g. sed 's/201401/2014\/01/' make generalize it you can use: sed 's/\(20[0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1\\\2/'

Answer (score 0):

```
Change  echo "\$InputFile_People=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\'${File_name}'" >>  ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm to  echo "\$InputFile_People=\$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\\${File_name}" >> "${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm" as given by Konsolexbox
```