# Through bash shell script, i am trying to read yearmonth from file name

Tags: bash

*Nb: this questions follows [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919063/trying-to-pass-the-string-value-to-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919063/trying-to-pass-the-string-value-to-print_)*

---

Through bash shell script, i am trying to read a file name (FACT_PEOPLE_201401.txt).

```
for File in `ls -1 ${OFSR_IN}/FACT_PEOPLE_*.txt
    do
         File_name=`basename ${File}`
         Ext_Year=`echo ${File_name} | cut -c 13-16`  #for YEAR
         Ext_Month=`echo ${File_name} | cut -c 17-18`  #for MONTH - trying to extract month

         echo ${EXT_Year}
         echo ${EXT_Month}
         EXT_YEARMTH_1=${Ext_Year}${var}${Ext_Month}  # concatenating year & month       

         echo "\$\$HR_YEARMONTH=${EXT_YEARMTH_1}" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm   # here outputing the value
```

I am trying to print the value of yearmonth (EXT_YEARMTH_1) in output file config.prm

```
echo "\$\$HR_YEARMONTH=${EXT_YEARMTH_1}" >> ${OFSR_CFG}/pmserver_OfsrHRSPeople05Loa.prm
```

but I am not able to print correct yearmonth such as 2014/01. Instead I am getting output as

```
$$HR_YEARMONTH=
```

I am expecting my output as without quotes in file name

```
$InputFile_People=$PMRootDir\rlhrs\data\in\FACT_PEOPLE_201306.txt
$$HR_YEARMONTH=2014/01
```

Comment: This has already been asked yesterday if I a not wrong. Without proper answer? I can't say because I am not able to retrieve that question. Deleted?

Comment: i asked yesterday using same script to read the file name. Now i got issue in populating yearmonth value. Since target program is expecting yearmonth value as 2014/01. but both are different question. script look may be same.

Comment: Maybe you should put a reference on that previous question in order to prevent such a confusion. Or avoid redundant questions and/or comments.

Comment: i will follow this standard definitely. sorry for this.

Comment: Here is many unrelated code, but missing the major info: what is the structure of your filenames? And what information want exactly extract from them? (e.g. show your filenames)

Comment: my file name is follows as: filename_201401.txt. i want to read one file at each time, extract yearmonth from file. then output as 2014/01

Comment: i am using the following code to extract year and month: Ext_Year=`echo ${File_name} | cut -c 13-16`  #for YEAR
         Ext_Month=`echo ${File_name} | cut -c 17-18`  #for MONTH

Comment: This is only an advice, but you should definitively **edit your question** to provide those informations. It will be more likely to be read than if it stay dug into comments.

Comment: sorry. i have given those info.

Comment: FYI, asking a new question that ignores advice you were given in your last one isn't a good way to encourage folks to help you further.

Comment: i felt there were so much discussion happened. i could not convey my question if i put the question again. Because of this i put it as new question.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
for file in FACT_PEOPLE*.txt
do
    sed 's:.*_\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\).txt:\1/\2:' <<< "$file"
done
```

for input

```
FACT_PEOPLE_201401.txt
```

will print

```
2014/01
```

If you want assign the year and month to variables, you can use:

```
for file in FACT_PEOPLE_*.txt
do
        read -r year month < <(sed 's:.*_\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\).txt:\1 \2:' <<< "$file")
        echo YEAR: $year
        echo MONTH: $month
done
```

what will print

```
YEAR: 2014
MONTH: 01
```

Comment: Ext_Year=`echo ${File_name} | cut -c 13-16`  #for YEAR
         Ext_Month=`echo ${File_name} | cut -c 17-18`  #for MONTH -- these two are not properly extracting year month

Comment: @user1468031 man, you should at least try my answer. you will see, it's extracting correctly...